# How can I copy all virtual methods to a derived class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I am deriving from a GameComponent class, and I would like to know if I get have VS2010 write me all the GameComponent class virtual methods in the derived class.

**EDIT:** I know about Initialize, Update, LoadContent etc. I also know that I can write override and it will suggest a list of methods for me. I was wondering if they could all be copied automatically (as overrides)?

Comment: It's there already... You derived them.

Answer (score 2):

There are two that you should *typically* override, Initialize and Update.  This really starts with understanding how you should implement a game component, a tool can be of little help.  IntelliSense does the grunt work, just write "public override" and it pops up a list of candidate methods that are overridable.  Tab to complete the proper declaration, the code inside the method body is completely yours to write.

Comment: It doesn't change my answer, the IntelliSense support for writing the method is what you've got.  They no doubt left this out on purpose to stop programmers from overriding *everything*.  It is different for an inherited interface, the IDE auto-generates its members automatically.  Because you have to.

Answer (score 0):

You will only have to rewrite the derived methods if you intend to redefine them.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228387(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to do: override them.

Comment: @MHA: no problem, after deriving, you should use the `override` or `new` modifiers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3(v=vs.100).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx

Comment: @MHA: now I saw your edit. I don't believe VS has this feature. I guess you will have to write all the methods down by hand (I mean, by keyboard; I mean, by intellisense ;)